# Yo Webapp: Error EACCES, permission denied 'Gruntfile.js'

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I am trying to install any yeoman generator and I always get always Error EACCESS, permission denied, since I switched to Linux.

```
 fs.js:432
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied 'Gruntfile.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:971:15)
    at Appgenerator.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-webapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/actions.js:217:10)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:336:15)
```

I am running node v0.10.29 and npm v1.4.14 and Zorin OS8 Codename Saucy. If I install "yo webapp-gulp" the error message says: "EACCES, permission denied 'Gulpfile.js'

I know "Error EACCES" is often here, and I seriously read of a lot threats, but nothing fitted yet. So thank you very much.

Edit:
Even bower won't work, because I get this message, if I want to install any package:

```
 Error: EACCES, open '/home/george/.cache/bower/packages/c667e980af216b85bcc1c0800106f136-2.0.5.lock'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

```
 chmod -R 777 .
```

On everything that is related with access denied. I know it is a bit much, but it works and is supposed to only work on my dev-machine.

Just get into the directory, which has the problem (for me it was the whole 'www' and 'home' directory (again I know it is not the best practice)) and run the chmod command from terminal.

Comment: chmod -R 777 is dangerous. You should fix your group permissions.

Comment: I would say this answer is something like that "bread today , hunger for tomorrow" ..much better if we understand what is the problem..I mean it is saw for a lot of people when you put this can be a solutions if someone doesn't get the risk on that is not beautiful at all

Answer (score 1):

It is happening to me as well because sometimes I run the bash like root. Well, I noticed with bower you can solve with this

```
--allow-root
```

at the end of the command.

By the way, it is not nice to get this every time that you are running a command, therefore what I would do

I saw your folder was .cache so it may be solved running before

```
bower cache clean
```

Just to give more ideas, although I am not sure

And if it is all about permission I would (In fact, I did it) do

```
chown -R youruser:youruser path/.cache/bower
```

but at the low level and never at this level "." . If it is not work I would try changing the permissions with that

```
chmod -R ... youruser:youruser path/.cache/bower
```

in the same level.

Bye